# Problems with "Config.Msi" directory while trying to recursively list all files from system root using java 8

Tags: java, arrays, file, directory, io

am trying to recursively list all files from system root, directories and single files, the code runs without any exception but when the code find "Config.Msi" as a directory it gave me an error on the function that list and find subdirectories.

```java
//Root path scan
for (File file : FilesInDisk) {
    if (file.isFile()){
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("[File Detected] => [ " + file.getName()+" ]");
        fileCache.add(fileIndex,file);
        System.out.println("[ Absolute path added to files cache ] [Details] => "+file.getAbsolutePath());
        fileIndex=fileIndex+1;
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    }

    else 
        if (file.isDirectory()){
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            //Walk into directory and walk more while directories still exist then return and go on with next one
            System.out.println("[Folder Detected] => [ " + file.getName()+" ]");
            System.out.println("[ Absolute path added to files cache ] [Details] => "+file.getAbsolutePath());
            subDirs(file);
            folderIndex=folderIndex+1;
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }
       System.out.println("=> Files Scanned: " + fileIndex);
       System.out.println("Scanning on progress...");
    } 
}
```

And this one is the subDirs function

```java
//Look inside directories.
public void subDirs(File ifile){
    File arrayDir[]=ifile.listFiles();
    for (File arr :arrayDir){
        System.out.println("===> " + arr);
    }  
}
```

```
[Folder Detected] => [ Config.Msi ]
[ Absolute path added to files cache ] [Details] => C:\Config.Msi
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at malwaredestroyer.MalwareDestroyer.subDirs(MalwareDestroyer.java:58)
    at malwaredestroyer.MalwareDestroyer.walk(MalwareDestroyer.java:89)
    at malwaredestroyer.MalwareDestroyer.main(MalwareDestroyer.java:100)
```

This is the error message that i receive from the ouput console,

Comment: It works in other directories but fails only in Config.Msi, one more thing that i found is that Config.Msi is not inside the root directory and is not a hidden file.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`File.listFiles()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) says:

> Returns: An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

So maybe an I/O error occurred and `null` was returned. However, it is difficult to tell if this is the actual problem.

In general it is recommended to use the classes of the `java.nio.file` package where possible because they throw exceptions in case of failures and their behavior is better defined.

For your use case [`Files.walkFileTree`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#walkFileTree-java.nio.file.Path-java.util.Set-int-java.nio.file.FileVisitor-) appears to be well suited.